# How do I get the current keyboard (current IME) being used via ADB

Tags: c#, android, shell, adb, ime

Currently, I know how to set the keyboard to use using the command `adb shell ime set [keyboard IME]`. But the question is how do I get the current keyboard being used?

I'm planning to use it using the `madb` [C# library](https://github.com/quamotion/madb) which fortunately has a `ExecuteRemoteCommand` method which allows me to execute shell commands (sort of like `adb shell`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
adb shell settings get secure default_input_method
```

Comment: In case of multiple devices/emulators, specify the one you want using the `-s` option. (`adb devices` will list them all.)